Is there any way to pass object to value of input in react-hook-form?
I would like to create delivery pick from objects using input type radio or select.
Here is my code:
interface IDelivery {
  id: number,
  name:string,
}

type FormFields = {
  delivery: IDelivery
}

const deliveries: IDelivery[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "QuickDelivery"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "UPS"
  }
]

function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<FormFields>()
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormFields> = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }
  
  return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <select {...register("delivery")}>
      {deliveries.map(d => <option value={d}>{d.name}</option>)}
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
}

export default App

The error i get is obviously that I can't assign values other than string or number etc.
What i have tried is assigning id value to input then getting delivery from array.
Also I have tried to set value using register options.
<input 
    type="radio" 
    value={JSON.stringify(delivery)} 
    {...register("delivery", {setValueAs: val => JSON.parse(val)})}
/>


Have you tried <option value={d.id}>{d.name}</option>?

Yes that would work but I want to set value as a whole object, not only id.

Than try <option value={JSON.stringify(d)}>{d.name}</option>

That would set form value as a string, I would like to directly set is as object

you should use Controller:
    <Controller
      name="delivery"
      control={control} // get this from useForm
      render={({ field: { value, onChange, ...rest } }) => (
        <select
          {...rest}
          value={value.id}
          onChange={(val) =>
            onChange({
              id: val.id,
              name: deliveries.filter((d) => d.id === val.id).name,
            })
          }>
          {deliveries.map((d) => (
            <option value={d.id}>{d.name}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
      )}
    />

but personally i prefer react-select for this use case because it let's you store values in object form.
